# How to apply slider to opencv video?

Tags: python, opencv, slider

So i try to make color selection with opencv. I use HSV color pallete to select the color. I use a variable named sensitivity to control the selection range. My code look like this:

```
sensitivity =30
low_green=(60 - sensitivity, 100, 50)  
high_green= (60 + sensitivity, 255, 255)
_, videoCam= vid.read()
f_height,f_width,_=videoCam.shape
hsv = cv.cvtColor(videoCam, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask1= cv.inRange(hsv, low_green , high_green )

mask1=cv.bitwise_not(mask1)
res = cv.bitwise_and(videoCam, videoCam, mask = mask1)
```

I want to use slider to control the sensitivity variable in real time, so i can adjust  color while viewing the result.

I read about slider in matplotlib, but i don't know if matplotlib can show cam captured video, and it will be laggy because i will have to plot the image every tick.

Is there a better way to get slider that can do realtime update and show the updated image in `cv.imshow`?

Comment: `cv2` has slider which you can add to `cv` window and assign function to this slider. Other side: `cv2` gives you `numpy.array` which you can display with `matplotlib`.

Comment: opencv has `createTrackbar`. use it. opencv has `imshow`.

Comment: [Python and OpenCV - How can I make a slider window in which I can use to change the value of parameters set? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428108/python-and-opencv-how-can-i-make-a-slider-window-in-which-i-can-use-to-change)

Comment: [cv2.createTrackbar using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047296/cv2-createtrackbar-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2` has slider - [createtrackbar](https://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.2/html/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#createtrackbar) - which you can add to window and assign function which will change `sensitivity`

**EDIT:**

- Run `createTrackbar()` only once - before loop.
- `createTrackbar()` needs function's name without `()`.
- Function has to get single value.
- Function has to use `global` to change value. (it can't use `return` because nobody can get this result)
- It need `namedWindow()` to create window because `createTrackbar()` needs its name.

```
import cv2

# --- functions ---

def change_sensitivity(value):
    global sensitivity  # inform function to assign value to global variable instead of local variable
    
    sensitivity = value
    #print('sensitivity:', sensitivity)
    
# --- main ---

sensitivity = 30   # global variable

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.createTrackbar('sensitivity', 'image', sensitivity, 60, change_sensitivity)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    #if frame is not None:
    if ret:

        low_green = (60 - sensitivity, 100, 50)  
        high_green= (60 + sensitivity, 255, 255)
        
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_green, high_green)
        mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
        
        frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

        cv2.imshow('image', frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff
    
    if key == 27:  # ESC
        break
    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: please vote to close as duplicate instead.

Comment: official guidelines say to post the answer to the earlier or more upvoted question, and mark the newer/less upvoted question to be a duplicate of the other one.